# Comma-code excerise how to remove comma with only two items in array

Tags: python

PS The book doesn't reach the join function yet so you have to use if,elif and else

So in the comma code exercise in automate the boring stuff you have to create a list and print it out using commas between each item and add 'and' before the last item.

Example

```
spam = ['apples','bana', 'apple']
def commacode(passedlist):
    stringy = ''
    if len(passedlist) == 1:
        stringy += str(passedlist[0])
        return stringy
    for i in range(len(passedlist)-1):
        stringy += str(passedlist[i]) + ', '
        # adds all except last item to str
    stringy += 'and ' + str(passedlist[len(passedlist)-1])
    # adds last item to string, after 'and'
    return stringy
print(commacode(spam))
```

outputs apples , bana, and apple.

However if it is only two items it would print out apples, and bana which isnt grammatically correct. So my question is how would I make it correct I tried adding a elif and else statement but it broke my code and I didn't save it to show you guys(sorry)

Comment: Can't use join  as we haven't reached that yet

Answer (score 1):

The joined string should starts with the first element, then build itself with all elements from 1 to second-to-last (there may be 0 of them). Returns it if the list only contains 1 element, or add  `and {last_element}` otherwise.

```py
def join_to_human_readable_list(elements):
  joined = str(elements[0])

  for element in elements[1:-1]:
    joined += f', {element}'

  return joined if len(elements) == 1 else f'{joined} and {elements[-1]}'
```

The function above will raise an `IndexError` if `elements` has a length of 0, if this is not what you need and you want to return an empty string instead, I believe you know how to do so.

Also, do remember to use good names. ["Readability counts."](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

Try it:

```py
print(join_to_human_readable_list(['apples']))                     # apples
print(join_to_human_readable_list(['apples', 'banana']))           # apples and banana
print(join_to_human_readable_list(['apples', 'banana', 'apple']))  # apples, banana and apple
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard.  The problem is pretty easy:

```
spam = ['apples','bananas', 'grapes']
def commacode(passedlist):
    return ', '.join(passedlist[:-1]) + ' and ' + passedlist[-1]
print(commacode(spam))
```

This fails if there's only one item, so an exercise for the reader is to check for and handle that with a simple `if`.

Comment: This hides all the complexity into the implementations of `join` and range indexing into arrays, which largely defeats the entire point of this exercise

Comment: Like Alexander said we didnt reach that point in the book yet you only use what you learn so far.

Answer (score 0):

```py
garbage = ['apples', 'goblins', 'cats', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

collector = ''
for i in range(len(garbage)):
    if i == len(garbage)-1: collector += 'and %s' % garbage[i]
    else: collector += '%s, ' % garbage[i]

print(collector)
```

Comment: This still outputs apples, and goblins which is not right grammar wise.

Comment: @Big_Port The comma before "*and*" is called a [serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). Grammatically speaking, it is not *entirely* wrong.